# Como matar un ciclo while True con la tecla enter

Tags: python, python-3.x

Como puedo terminar un ciclo while True usando un salto de linea?
tengo esta pequeña función:

```
def number_add():
    print("\033[1;33m"+"Please enter two numbers: \n" + "\033[;36m"+ "Operator 1: ", end='')
    a = input()
    print("\033[;36m"+"Operator 2: ",end='')
    b = input()
    print("\033[4;35m"+"Result: %s + %s = %s" %(a, b, str(int(a) + int(b))))
    while True:
        if input() == '\n':
            break
    clear()
```

cuando intento terminarla con la tecla enter no funciona, solo hace un salto de linea en la consola, cuál es el error?

Comment: No sé que pretendes con el `while True`, pero `input()` nunca te va a retornar `\n`, sino que quedará esperando a que el usuario teclee una línea y pulse intro, y entonces te retornará _la línea tecleada_, pero sin el retorno de carro. Si el usuario no escribe nada y pulsa INTRO sin más, entonces `input()` te retornará la cadena vacía `''`. No obstante esa entrada no es "en tiempo real", cualquier otra tecla que pulse el usuario se va acumulando en la "linea" que se está leyendo, hasta que se pulse intro. Si quieres recibir en tiempo real los caracteres tecleados, mira la respuesta de @NEA

Answer (score 4):

Para trabajar con el teclado deberas tener la librería keyboard. Te adjunto un ejemplo sencillo.

```
import keyboard

while True:

    print('Me imprimo infinitamente hasta que presionen la tecla esc')

    if keyboard.is_pressed('esc'):
        break
```

Como comenta Abulafia para instalarlo deberás emplear `pip`:

```
pip install keyboard
```

Te adjunto la [documentación](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/).

¡Saludos!

Comment: Convendría señalar que no se trata de un módulo estándar python, sino de una librería de terceros que hay que instalar con `pip`.

Answer (score 0):

en lugar de usar directamente un True para el while sería bueno que utilices una variable booleana con un valor True, y cuando presiones la tecla cambias la variable a False. Con respecto a la tecla que presiones sería bueno que uses eventos para el teclado.

Comment: como sería un ejemplo de esto en este caso?

Comment: En vez de citar, explica con ejemplos de codigo lo que en la respuesta tratas. mira [answer] para más info

Answer (score 0):

No sé a qué te refieres. Si lo que quieres es esperar a un enter para continuar no es necesario un while.

```
null_input = input()
doSomething()
```

Answer (score 0):

Como input es una cadena (por defecto) simplemente evalua que esta no sea nula, si es nula es porque dicha cadena no existe, si colocas `'/n'` estas evaluando un salto de linea en vez de como tal un **vacio**, si lo que quieres es que cuando teclees **Enter** se salga, evalualo asi:

```
a=input()
while True:
    print(a)
    if a=='':
        break
    a=input()
```

Ademas si quieres que el codigo siga por el ciclo evaluando mientras *unicamente* la variable**a** sea diferente de vacio, lo puedes dejar asi:

```
def number_add():
    a = input("\033[1;33m"+"Please enter two numbers: \n" + "\033[;36m"+ "Operator 1: ")
    while True:
        if a=='':
            break
        b = input("\033[;36m"+"Operator 2: ")
        print("\033[4;35m"+"Result: %s + %s = %s" %(a, b, str(int(a) + int(b))))
        a = input("\033[1;33m"+"Please enter two numbers: \n" + "\033[;36m"+ "Operator 1: ")

number_add()
```

En el momento en que **a** sea vacio se rompe el ciclo y no evalua mas.

Answer (score -2):

@Kevin tiene razón. Y creo que puede referirse a algo parecido a esto.

```py
def number_add():
    print("\033[1;33m"+"Please enter two numbers: \n" + "\033[;36m"+ "Operator 1: ", end='')
    a = input()
    print("\033[;36m"+"Operator 2: ",end='')
    b = input()
    print("\033[4;35m"+"Result: %s + %s = %s" %(a, b, str(int(a) + int(b))))
    c = input() #no se si el intro puede recogerse así
    d = True
    while d:
        if c == '\n': #tampoco estoy seguro de si esto es correcto
           d = False
    clear()
```

No se si la sintaxis es exactamente así, yo de python no he visto mucho.

Un saludo!

Comment: Eso no funcionará por la razón que explico en mi comentario a la pregunta del usuario. Además está mal indentado, por lo que es sintácticamente incorrecto (pues en python la indentación es parte de la sintaxis). Además el `//` es otro error de sintaxis pues en python el comentario es `#`

Comment: Creo haber dejado claro que no se de python. Por si acaso no lo has leido te lo repito entrecomillado: "No se si la sintaxis es exactamente así, yo de python no he visto mucho."

Comment: Sí, lo había leido, y por eso no he puntuado negativo. Se te agradece el intento de colaborar, pero dar una respuesta errónea es contraproducente, pues puede crear confusión en otros usuarios que puedan venir con la misma duda. Y por eso precisamente te corrijo, para que lo retoques o elimines la respuesta. No seamos tan susceptibles por favor, Aqui todos estamos para aprender.

Comment: @abulafia tiene razón. Si no dominas el lenguaje es mejor no poner una respuesta ya que induces a error al OP. Por no decir que el tono que has utilizado en tu comentario no es el más adecuado.

Comment: Si no manejas el lenguaje python muy bien no deberias contestar dicha pregunta, podrias confundir a las personas que preguntan ya que recuerda en general son personas que estan aprendiendo y no son expertas en el tema.